# Javascript date has two different values depending on in what context it is printed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm seeing some weirdness where a Date-object has one value when outputted as part of an object, as compared to when it is outputted by itself. The following code-snippet plus output probably best explains the issue I'm having. Of specific interest is `$scope.firstDateOfWeek`.

```
$scope.month = $scope.month - 1;
$scope.firstDateOfMonth = new Date($scope.year, $scope.month);
$scope.firstDay = $scope.firstDateOfMonth.getDay();
$scope.firstDateOfWeek = new Date($scope.year, $scope.month, 2 - $scope.firstDay);
$scope.lastDate = new Date(new Date($scope.year, $scope.month + 1) - 1);

console.log($scope);
console.log($scope.firstDateOfWeek);
console.log($scope);
console.log($scope.firstDateOfWeek);
console.log($scope);
console.log($scope.firstDateOfWeek);
```

Output (the same x 3):

[image]

To be specific, when I do console.log($scope), then $scope.firstDateOfWeek get's printed out as 2015-02-02, but when I explicitly print the variable, console.log($scope.firstDateOfWeek), then it gets printed as 2014-12-29.

Anyone have an idea on why this is?

EDIT: After the comment by Hacketo, here is the rest of the code.

```
var dates = [];

currentDate = $scope.firstDateOfWeek;
for (i = 0;
     (currentDate <= $scope.lastDate ||
     (currentDate > $scope.lastDate && currentDate.getDay() != 1)); i++) {

    if (currentDate.getMonth() == $scope.month) {
        dates.push(new Date(currentDate));

    } else {
        dates.push(null);
    }
    currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
}
```

What is happening is that currentDate holds a reference to $scope.firstDateOfWeek, which is getting updated in the for loop.

The only question-mark that remains is then asynchronous behaviour that is showed by console.log(). Could someone explain that?

Comment: it may be a reference that's keeped by the console , firstDateOfWeek is modified after and the console update the $scope object properties (But not a directly printed one as it return string : $scope.firstDateOfWeek). Is there any other modifications of the firstDateOfWeek after your code ?

Comment: Did you really give all your code? If yes, try it in another browser.

Comment: You are correct Hacketo. Updated question.